# How do I view the storage of a Chrome Extension I've installed?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, local-storage, google-chrome-devtools

It seems like it should be possible to view the `localStorage`/`chrome.storage` of Chrome Extensions installed on my browser. I've played around with the Developer Tools a bit, but haven't found a way to do this. Any ideas?

Answer (score 119):

I will proceed to amalgamate the existing knowledge present in several answers, into a simple and comprehensive one. **If you vote up this one, please do the same with the ones from @mwkwok and @chaohuang.**

It is true that stuff saved using `chrome.storage` does not show up in developer tools, there you can only see stuff saved using regular localStorage API. Do this:

1. Open your extension's **background page** by going to `chrome://extensions/` ("Developer mode" needs to be checked to see background pages)
2. Go to the `Console` tab and type this:

`chrome.storage.local.get(console.log)`

This will spit the whole storage as a JSON object into the console.

Comment: The slightly shorter equivalent is `chrome.storage.local.get(console.log)`. There's also `chrome.storage.sync.get(console.log)`!

Comment: It says `storage` is undefined

Comment: `chrome.storage.sync.get(console.dir)`  shows a formatted view

Answer (score 110):

There is a very helpful extension to work with both `localStorage` and `chrome.storage` that I recently discovered, that works as a Dev Tools panel.

[Storage Area Explorer](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/storage-area-explorer/ocfjjjjhkpapocigimmppepjgfdecjkb)

[image]

I did not write this, but it was suggested by the author on some other SO question.

Comment: Wish I could +50 this.

Comment: I tried this out, but it's not working for me. However, I'm actually developing a Chrome "devtools" extension - not a normal Chrome extension.

Comment: @nogridbag Try opening the Dev Tools for your Dev Tools. Undock, Ctrl+Shift+I. ..wait, I tried. Do not do this with Storage Area Explorer if you're epileptic!

Comment: Yeah I noticed the same thing :)

Comment: This appears to be broken now.

Comment: Works great! (Tested with my own unpacked extension in development)

Comment: If you wish to see the data items from `chrome.storage` you can open dev tools for background.js of your extension then click on the _storage explorer_ in that window.

Comment: To me it does not show content of `chrome.storage` as of Chrome 80 (March 2020)

Comment: add the native way to access and then promote the extension if it works

Comment: @CodingEdgar Not sure why you're angry at me for that. Other answers cover manual "run a snippet of code" answers. There isn't a native DevTools interface for it.

Comment: Sorry @Xan , didn't mean to be rude, I just thought that it could be a good way to improve your answer. stating the fact there's no native way and then promoting the extension is a more complete answer, otherways it looks just like promo, not angry at you at all, cheers.

Comment: Am I doing something wrong? This has too many upvotes, but when I install and open the Storage Explorer, all I can see is the local storage and session storage tabs... There's no option to view an extension's storage...

Comment: @callmekatootie Seems not to work with service worker based extensions, sadly.

Answer (score 68):

You're right that chrome.storage does not show up in developer tools. The only way I've found to view all of it is by putting this into console:

```
chrome.storage.local.get(function(result){console.log(result)})
```

This will spit the JSON object into console.

Comment: It says `storage` is undefined

Answer (score 48):

This was actually two questions!

1. How do I view **localStorage** of a Chrome Extension I've installed?

Open the Chrome Devtool by clicking on the background page of an extension in Chrome://extensions/ (Developer mode needs to be checked to see background pages), then in resource panel you can see the local storage on the left. (by chaohuang and Kil)

2. How do I view **chrome.storage** of a Chrome Extension I've installed?

In the same console of the background page:

**OPEN THE BACKGROUND PAGE FIRST**:

a. to go to chrome://extensions/

b. ensure you are in development mode

c. then on your extension, either click "Inspect views background page" or go to "Details" and click background page.

**NOW THAT YOU ARE ON THE BACKGROUND PAGE YOU CAN PROCEED**:

- For storage.local (by mwkwok)

`chrome.storage.local.get(function(result){console.log(result)})`

- For storage.sync

`chrome.storage.sync.get(function(result){console.log(result)})`

Comment: Should be accepted as the correct answer, the answer below requires an Add-on to be installed and doesn't work.

Comment: With Chrome 80 I get following error when trying to use `chrome.storage.local.get` in the console: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'local' of undefined at <anonymous>:1:16. The  `chrome.storage` value is undefined in the console.

Comment: @suma Did you try it in a console of a normal page?

Comment: I see now. I need to open **the backround page**, as written in the answer. Perhaps the answer could include how to navigate to the background page, for naive users like me who have no idea what it is.

Comment: @Suma The way to do this is to go to `chrome://extensions/`, ensure you are in development mode, then on your extension, either click "Inspect views background page" or go to "Details" and click background page. Then you can access your variables.

Comment: It says `storage` is undefined

Comment: upvoting as the correct answer. it's not the shortest, but it is the most detailed. sometimes when you've reached the end of the rabbit hole and are exhausted it's nice to have verbose, obvious instruction.

Comment: also, note for 2021: 'inspect view' works for service workers, in the case you've updated your extension for MVC3

Answer (score 18):

Open the Chrome Devtool by clicking on the background page of an extension in `Chrome://extensions/` (`Developer mode` needs to be checked to see background pages), then in resource panel you can see the local storage on the left.

Comment: You can find it in Chrome Developers Tool if you use `LocalStorage API`. But if you use `chrome.storage API` method like `chrome.storage.local.set({"key":value})`, data is not stored in there. Where can we find those datas?

Comment: Not seeing anything my extension saved. Other than just print it out, is there another way to check them out?

Comment: Check out recently added answer from @Xan.

Comment: **Does this even work?** What you see there is the HTML5 storage, not chrome.storage storage

Comment: Can't see anything of the sort

Answer (score 15):

In 2022, the best way I've found is still with the console.log, but you can make it a lot cleaner-looking with currying. Open up extensions page, open the inspector for your background worker, go to console, and...

`chrome.storage.local.get(console.log)`

Answer (score 9):

I didn't get any results using the provided code typed into console. But this code worked when put into the console.

`chrome.storage.sync.get(null, function (data) { console.info(data) });`

The difference here is that we pass a null value which will return all content in the storage. To back this up, and for additional reading, check out the [official chrome page on this API.](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage#property-sync)

Answer (score -1):

You should try the latest Storage Area Viewer. It’s more modern and feature-rich. You’ll definitely come back to thank me.

[Storage Area Viewer](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/storage-area-viewer/fcbndbpibgeafoogbmbcljcmgakaniae?hl=en)