# Can't view chrome extension local storage from developers tool but can access it from extension api

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

As title says I can access extension local storage through api but can't see any keys and values through developer tools. Below is the code which I use to store and get keys in local storage.

Storing value

`chrome.storage.sync.set({
        'handle': any-variable-which-have-some-value
      });`

Accessing value

`chrome.storage.sync.get('handle', function (savedHandle) {
        console.log(savedHandle.handle);
      });`

So how can I see stored values from developer tools?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I view the storage of a Chrome Extension I've installed?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922964/how-do-i-view-the-storage-of-a-chrome-extension-ive-installed)

Comment: Thanks @HaibaraAi ! This worked but is there any way to access it directly without any need of extension?

Edit: This answer is good http://stackoverflow.com/a/27432365/4984269 . Thanks

Comment: yes, just remember to switch to the context of your extension, it will ensure `chrome.storage` is defined.

Comment: @HaibaraAi can you post this ans http://stackoverflow.com/a/27432365/4984269 on this question? I'll mark that question as answer, that'll give you some points

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open F12 tool and **switch to the context of your extension**, then type your code in console, you will get the storage.

### Updated:

The following answer just provides some alternatives, check it out.
[How do I view the storage of a Chrome Extension I've installed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922964/how-do-i-view-the-storage-of-a-chrome-extension-ive-installed/27432365#27432365)